# Get list of profits from past 7 days, including days with no sales

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, data-warehouse

I'm trying to output a table that reads a table of profits and returns total made day by day for the past week. Example

```
profits:
id  timestamp_sell     profit_unit  profit_quantity
1   2015-11-10 08:00:01    20         3  
2   2015-11-09 07:05:00    10         3
3   2015-11-06 11:25:03    20         3
4   2015-11-10 23:00:02    30         1
```

should output something like:

```
date ----    profit made
2015-11-06   60
2015-11-07   0
2015-11-08   0
2015-11-09   30
2015-11-10   90
```

At first I wrote something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp(
dates DATETIME NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO temp( dates ) 
VALUES (
DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -1
DAY )), (
DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2
DAY )), (
DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -3
DAY )) , (
DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -4
DAY )) , (
DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -5
DAY )), (
DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -6
DAY )) , (
DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -7
DAY ));

select date(profit.timestamp_sell), sum(coalesce(profit.profit_unit*profit.quantity_profit,0)) as total
from profit
right join temp ON DATE(temp.dates) = DATE(profit.timestamp_sell)
where date(profit.timestamp_sell) <= NOW() 
and date(profit.timestamp_sell) >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 7 day)
group by date(timestamp_sell)
```

I created a temp table with all the dates I need (last 7 days) and joined them with the result set to avoid empty rows during days with no sales, but even then the result is the same (it still skips all days with no records).

Any suggestions on how to tackle this differently?

Comment: you should clean up the sql a bit. you're using `now()` which generates a datetime value, and comparing it against `date()` values, which is date ONLY (no time).

Comment: Your approach is fine in principle. Other options include either a calendar or integer utility table, or (my preference) handling the logic of missing results in the presentation layer (e.g. a bit of PHP)

Comment: @Strawberry I tried this: SELECT calendar.date, 
CASE WHEN SUM( profit.profit_unit * profit.quantity_profit ) IS NULL 
THEN 0 
ELSE SUM( profit.profit_unit * profit.quantity_profit ) 
END 
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN profit ON ( DATE( profit.timestamp_sell ) = calendar.date ) 
WHERE calendar.date >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 7 
DAY ) 
GROUP BY calendar.date. calendar is a table created with every date from the past 1 years with a stored procedure.
and it still doesent work...